# Adding elements(text, events) based on player location

Tags: c#, console

I'm creating a framework for my personal use, which allows me to create environments, entities, items etc...
Now, I wanna be able to retrieve the location that I just created and do something with it. Like a said location must have that types of monsters, there might be a blacksmith to help me forge new weapons, and since it's a text-based game, I wanna link some text to those locations.

I've got a list that's populated  in a World class like so:

```
Environment.Environments.Add(new Environment("Dark Forest", "A very dark... very frightening place...", true, true));
```

Here's the big bad code:

```
class Environment
{      
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public bool ContainsItems { get; set; }
    public bool ContainsEntities { get; set; }
    public static List<Environment> Environments = new List<Environment>(); 

    public Environment(string name, string description, bool containsItems, bool containEntities)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        ContainsItems = containsItems;
        ContainsEntities = containEntities;
    }

    public void SetLocation()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine();
        DisplayText("You arrived at {0}", Name);
        DisplayText(Description);
        Console.ReadKey();

        if (ContainsItems)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            DisplayText("If you look carefully, you might find something valuable!");
            if(ContainsEntities)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                DisplayText("Proceed with caution, some monsters hides here!");
            }               
        }
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;            
    }  
}
```

I tried different things, like adding events that are linked to one of my command "Look", but I'm not sure if it's the right tool for my needs and I must say, I never used events till now! So if you were to implement something like this, how would you go about it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a grid system with locations. Give an x/y coordinate, with collections of details (Items and Creatures (don't use "entity" it has its own meaning)).

```
public class Environment
{
   public List<Location> Locations {set; get;}
   public Location CurrentLocation {get; set;}
   public Environment()
   {
       Locations = new List<Locations> {...} //set up Locations in a grid
       public Location Move(string direction)
       {
        //check to see if there is a location in the direction the user wants to move
        //if so, load the new Location into CurrentLocation. If not, throw an exception
       }
   }
}

public class Location
{
   public List<Item> Items {set; get;}
   public List<Creature> Creatures {set; get;}
   public int X {get; set;} 
   public int Y {get; set;}
   public void OnLoaded()
   {
       //here is where you check if there are items, or creatures, etc, simply by counting the list...
   } 
}
```